# onclick of an d3 event should store the value in a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

Here after on click of the checkbox,I need to take the all checked client_ip values into a texbox of div ip.

MyCode:

```
 <html>
    <body>
    <div id="ipDiv">
    Client_ip :<input type="text" id ="ip" name="client_ip"/>
    </div>
    </body>
    <script>
    var tabulate = function (data,columns) {
    var svg = d3.select("#ip").append("svg");
      var table = d3.select('#example')
        var thead = table.append('thead')
        var tbody = table.append('tbody')

        thead.append('tr')
          .selectAll('th')
            .data(columns)
            .enter()
          .append('th')
            .text(function (d) { return d })

        var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
            .data(data)
            .enter()
          .append('tr')

        var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
            .data(function(row) {
                return columns.map(function (column) {
                    return { column: column, value: row[column] }
              })
          })
          .enter()
        .append('td')
       .text(function (d) { return d.value })
       .append("input")
       .attr("id","change")
       .attr("type", "checkbox")
       .style("float","left")
    .on("click", function(d,i) { alert(d.value) });

      return table;
    }
    </script>
    </html>
```

onclick of checkbox should automatically store in a texbox.
Can anyone please suggest on this issue..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can append the value to the existing textbox

```
    .on("click", function(d,i) { 
    alert(d.value);
    $('input#id').val(function( index, val ) {
        return val + d.value;
    })
  });
```

for returning an array change  `return val + d.value`:

```
var arr = val.trim().length > 1 ? val.split(',') : []; //split textbox value in to array
arr.push(d.value); //add id to array
return arr.join(',');
```

if you want to set the value of textbox to comma separated values of checkboxes on click of checkbox, the easiest way is

```
.on("click", function(d,i) { 
        alert(d.value);
        var csv = $(':checkbox[id=change]:checked').map(function(){return this.value;}).get().join(',');
        $('input#id').val(csv);

});
```

Comment: In place of "input#id",do I need to keep like this,                        .on("click", function(d,i) { 
alert(d.value);
$('#ip').val(function( index, val ) {
    return val + d.value;
});

Comment: you got both div and input id's as ip. using input#id will restrict the selector to textbox

Comment: k,it is working fine now.Now I am getting all the values in a text box.But I want to separate all the values by a comma.Then how can we do that?

Comment: I did like this  return val +','+ d.value; But it is including comma for the first value also.          Eg:  ,192.168.7.1,192.168.7.100

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur suggestion.Its really helpful.

Comment: Here it is returning the value when the checkbox is deselected also.Because I have used on click event.I want to return a value to a textbox only when a checkbox is selected.

Comment: can you post your working code on jsfiddle? I will modify it

Comment: ksure .I 'll post it on jsfiddle

Comment: Finally I got the desired result by adding  this code  "arr.splice(index, 1);"

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur info

Comment: By using the edited code ,I'm getting "on" as a value of csv instead of a client_ip